# NotificationCenter is not available when building for watchOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I want to use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) inside a watchOS target. But I get the following error message when building the app at `import NotificationCenter`:

```
NotificationCenter is not available when building for watchOS Simulator.
Consider using `#if !os(watchOS)` to conditionally import this framework.
```

How do you handle this situation? Can I no longer use the simulator?

Comment: `Notification Center` framework is deprecated. Use [WidgetKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit) instead.

Comment: No, it's not. I mean [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) not [Notification Center](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter).

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the error?

Comment: It's at `import NotificationCenter`.

Comment: What kind of notifications are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I mixed things up. All I want to do in my watchOs framework was something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(...)
```

The class with `import NotificationCenter` was in the wrong framework. No need for such a class in a watchOs framework. So my problem is fixed.